# Python list comprehension limits

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I need to scan two lists, of which one is a list of lists. Then i need to build a matrix out of this scan.
The first list, l1, contains some elements, while l2 contains lists of l1's grouped elements.

```
l1 = ['el1', 'el2', 'el3', 'el4']
l2 = [['el1', 'el3'],['el3'],['el2', 'el3', 'el4']]
```

The matrix i need to build has to have a number of columns equal to the number of elements of l1, while the number of lists inside l2 defines the number of rows. Refering to the provided lists, the matrix should have this form:

```
  | 1 0 1 0 |
A=| 0 0 1 0 |
  | 0 1 1 1 |
```

each row entry is 1 if the elements belongs to the general list l1, 0 otherwise.

Since i'd like to solve this in an efficient way without using numpy or any other useful module, i tried with list comprehension:

```
A = [[0 for el in range(len(l1))] for el in range(len(l2))]
```

But i'm having problems defining the specific entry: creating the matrix and then updating each entry based on a second scan is too consuming, since im dealing with a gigantic dataset. How can i specify which value to insert inside the list comprehension itself? I tried with something like:

```
A = [[(1 if item in l1 else 0 for item in l2) for el in range(len(l1))] for el in range(len(l2))]
```

but i understand it doesnt make much sense. Maybe this is a trivial and pretty obvious problem but im just a student trying to pave its way into the language.

Comment: "creating the matrix and then updating each entry based on a second scan is too consuming" I find that highly unlikely. Have you actually profiled that approach? What size of lists are we talking about?

Comment: the dataset im dealing with has a little more than 500k rows with 7 values per row.

Comment: That's tiny. Just iterate over it twice.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
res = [[int(lj in li) for lj in l1] for li in l2]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

As an alternative, convert to set to speed up the inner list comprehension:

```
res = [[int(lj in si) for lj in l1] for si in map(set, l2)]
```

To understand better you could converting to a for loop and adding a few print statements is always helpful:

```
res = []
for i, li in enumerate(l2):
    row = [int(lj in li) for lj in l1]
    res.append(row)
    print(f"row {i}", li)
    print([f"{lj} in row: {v}" for v, lj in zip(row, l1)])
```

**Output**

```
row 0 ['el1', 'el3']
['el1 in row: 1', 'el2 in row: 0', 'el3 in row: 1', 'el4 in row: 0']
row 1 ['el3']
['el1 in row: 0', 'el2 in row: 0', 'el3 in row: 1', 'el4 in row: 0']
row 2 ['el2', 'el3', 'el4']
['el1 in row: 0', 'el2 in row: 1', 'el3 in row: 1', 'el4 in row: 1']
```